# What is meant by javascript:// in the href of a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom-events

Yesterday, I visited a forum. There was like and Dislike button under the each post. When I click the Like button, the Like was counted without any page reload. Meaning Ajax was working, but when I check the href of that like link that was like this:

```
<a href="javascript://" name="dbtech_thanks_button" data-postid="1369522" data-button="likes" style="padding-right:6px;"><img src="dbtech/thanks/images/likes.png" alt="Likes" title="Likes"> Like</a>
```

I have also checked (using Visual Event) that there is no event listener attached to that link. So, I cant understand that how it works. Can some one explain?

Comment: Javascript: is not a valid protocol.

Answer (score 1):

```
javascript: return 0;
```

Does the same thing.

This would just uselessly create a random regular expression literal and then discard it. It is probably some programmer's ignorance.

This is included because an `a` tag has to have an `href`.

Answer (score 0):

On its own, a link with `href="javascript://"` does nothing at all when clicked. This is as opposed to a link with `href="#"`, which will set the anchor of the current location to `#`, or a blank or unset `href`, which will cause navigation to the current page.

In this case, since there's no explicit `onclick` handler and no event handler attached to this link, there must be some a event handler at a higher level that's catching click events as they bubble up to the page. Without being able to see the site, it's impossible to say for sure how it's working, but my guess would be that the `data-button="likes"` attribute is involved here.

Comment: the website is www.siasat.pk. Can You please have a look and get some idea about how this like and dislike button work?

Comment: I don't see any such button. Probably only appears for logged-in users, and I'm not going to register an account just to investigate.